# Bottle.py error routing

Tags: python, bottle

Bottle.py ships with an import to handle throwing HTTPErrors and route to a function.

Firstly, the documentation claims I can (and so do several examples):

```
from bottle import error

@error(500)
def custom500(error):
    return 'my custom message'
```

however, when importing this statement error is unresolved but on running the application ignores this and just directs me to the generic error page.

I found a way to get around this by:

```
from bottle import Bottle

main = Bottle()

@Bottle.error(main, 500)
def custom500(error):
    return 'my custom message'
```

But this code prevents me from embedding my errors all in a separate module to control the nastiness that would ensue if I kept them in my main.py module because the first argument has to be a bottle instance.

So my questions:

1. Has anyone else experienced this?
2. why doesn't *error* seem to resolve in only my case (I installed from *pip install bottle*)?
3. Is there a seamless way to import my error routing from a separate python module into the main application?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to embed your errors in another module, you could do something like this:

*error.py*

```
def custom500(error):
    return 'my custom message'

handler = {
    500: custom500,
}
```

*app.py*

```
from bottle import *
import error

app = Bottle()
app.error_handler = error.handler

@app.route('/')
def divzero():
    return 1/0

run(app)
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
from bottle import error, run, route, abort

@error(500)
def custom500(error):
    return 'my custom message'

@route("/")
def index():
    abort("Boo!")

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases I find it's better to subclass Bottle. Here's an example of doing that and adding a custom error handler.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bottle import Bottle, response, Route

class MyBottle(Bottle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Bottle.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.error_handler[404] = self.four04
        self.add_route(Route(self, "/helloworld", "GET", self.helloworld))
    def helloworld(self):
        response.content_type = "text/plain"
        yield "Hello, world."
    def four04(self, httperror):
        response.content_type = "text/plain"
        yield "You're 404."

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mybottle = MyBottle()
    mybottle.run(host='localhost', port=8080, quiet=True, debug=True)
```