# How to handle error 5xx with python bottle

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I know how to handle any error codes, like 404:

```
@app.error(404)  # changed from OP
def error404(error):
    log.info('APP 404')
    return 'Nothing here, sorry'
```

But how can a 5xx error code (any) be handled with Bottle Framework?
I can't do it for 500, 503 and so on...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bottle.py error routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174886/bottle-py-error-routing)

Comment: but that still expects having a handler for each error code...